# Авто-замена значений в google spreadsheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть две таблицы, одна из которых импортирует данные через `=IMPORTRANGE` данные из другой.
Я создаю копии обеих табличек, но поскольку URL не меняется на url новой таблички, данные черпаются из исходной.

И вот мой вопрос:
Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы URL менялся автоматически во всех ячейках с старого на новый?
Раньше я это делал вручную, так как таких ячеек было <30, а сейчас уже более 150 и вручную это делать крайне напряжно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможный выход - делать импорт не через формулы, а скриптом. Тогда url , как переменную нужно будет прописать один раз в коде.